# Regular Expression to Match 4 characters then the next 6 characters then the next 5 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want this string:

`378282246310005`

With a regex, I want to return groups of 4 characters, then the next 6, then the next 5. Like this:

`3782 822463 10005`

**Edit**

I also want to have partial matches, so this string:

`378` will return `378`

and

`37822822` will return `3782 822`

Comment: What's the problem? Use the `{n}` modifier regexp to match `n` characters.

Comment: -1, make it clear when you edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about matching digits and [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

`\d` is a [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) matching one digit

`{Min,Max}` is matching at least Min and at most Max times. `{x}` is matching x times.

You would need also [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), either `^` and `$` when the number is the complete string or [wordboundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` before and ahead, when the number is somewhere in the text.

Then you need to [capture the matched groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), to be able to retrive the result.

Then you end up here:

```
^(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d{5})$
```

Your numbers are then in the capturing groups 1, 2 and 3.

For your partial match requirement you can use this:

```
^(\d{1,4})(\d{0,6})(\d{0,5})$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36dd3)

Comment: -1, where is the partial match?

Comment: In that case it's his bad, but I can't reverse it unless you edit.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to the partial matches requirement, I guess the regex you're looking for should be like this:

```
  /(^\d{1,4})(?:(\d{1,6})(\d{1,5})?)?/
```

Test:

```
> r = /(^\d{1,4})(?:(\d{1,6})(\d{1,5})?)?/
> s = "378282246310005"
> while(s) { console.log(s.match(r)); s = s.substr(0, s.length - 1) }

["378282246310005", "3782", "822463", "10005", index: 0, input: "378282246310005"]
["37828224631000", "3782", "822463", "1000", index: 0, input: "37828224631000"]
["3782822463100", "3782", "822463", "100", index: 0, input: "3782822463100"]
["378282246310", "3782", "822463", "10", index: 0, input: "378282246310"]
["37828224631", "3782", "822463", "1", index: 0, input: "37828224631"]
["3782822463", "3782", "822463", undefined, index: 0, input: "3782822463"]
["378282246", "3782", "82246", undefined, index: 0, input: "378282246"]
["37828224", "3782", "8224", undefined, index: 0, input: "37828224"]
["3782822", "3782", "822", undefined, index: 0, input: "3782822"]
["378282", "3782", "82", undefined, index: 0, input: "378282"]
["37828", "3782", "8", undefined, index: 0, input: "37828"]
["3782", "3782", undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: "3782"]
["378", "378", undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: "378"]
["37", "37", undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: "37"]
["3", "3", undefined, undefined, index: 0, input: "3"]
```

Comment: this is really close. but see this: when the input is "3782" it return s ["3782", "3782"]. How can I make it only return ["3782"] ?

Comment: @dylanjha: this is how `match` works - the first elem is always the whole match. Use `str.match(r).slice(1)`.

Comment: @dylanjha: BTW, other answers here are better. My expr is overcomplicated

Comment: what is it about this regex: `/\d{4}(?=\d{2,3})|\d+/g` that when I match against it it doesn't return the full string as the first part of the match?

Comment: @dylanjha: in the `g` mode `match` acts differently.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
/^(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})$/
```

If you specifically want to match digits, replace `.` with `\d`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

EDIT:
Since you also want partial matching, you can do this:

```
 /^(.{1,4})(.{0,6})(.{0,5})$/
```